# Rank requirement to compute product $\mathbf{A'Bc}$ if $\mathbf{Ac}$ is known

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

Assume real matrices:

$$\mathbf{A}:m\times n$$
$$\mathbf{A'}:m'\times k$$
$$\mathbf{B}:k\times n$$
$$\mathbf{c}:n\times 1$$

with the constraint that $m+m'=n$. The value of $\mathbf{Ac}$ is assumed to be known. I am looking for a condition under which the value of $\mathbf{A'Bc}$ can be computed exactly. It seems that the condition is
$$rank\left(\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{A}\\
\mathbf{A'B}\\
\end{bmatrix}\right)=m$$
based on a proof where the problem is stated, i.e., the above concatenation of matrices has full column rank. But I don't understand the reason. Is this is a necessary or a sufficient condition too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any row vector can be uniquely decomposed as the sum of two row vectors: a vector in the row space of $\mathbf{A}$, and the other vector orthogonal to the row space of $\mathbf{A}$ (i.e., they belong to the null space of $\mathbf{A}$).

Let $\mathbf{A}^{\perp}\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times n}$ be a matrix such that its row space spans the null space of $\mathbf{A}$, i. e., $\mathbf{A}^{\perp}\mathbf{A}^T=\mathbf{0}$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A'}\mathbf{B}&= \mathbf{Q}\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{R}\mathbf{A}^{\perp}\\
\mathbf{c}^T&= \mathbf{q}^T\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{r}^T\mathbf{A}^{\perp},
\end{align} where $\mathbf{Q}\in\mathbb{R}^{m'\times m}$, $\mathbf{R}\in\mathbb{R}^{m'\times p}$, $\mathbf{q}\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times m}$ and $\mathbf{r}\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times p}$.

Thus, we obtain
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A'}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{c}&= \mathbf{Q}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{c}+\mathbf{R}\mathbf{A}^{\perp}\mathbf{c}\\
\mathbf{A}\mathbf{c}&= \mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{q}.
\end{align} 
Since $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{c}$ has no information about $\mathbf{A}^{\perp}\mathbf{c}$, we get that $\mathbf{A'}\mathbf{B}= \mathbf{Q}\mathbf{A}$. Hence, the necessary and sufficient condition is $$
\mathrm{Rank}\left\{\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{A}\\\mathbf{A'}\mathbf{B}\end{bmatrix}\right\}=\mathrm{Rank}\left\{\mathbf{A}\right\}.$$

In other words, $
\mathrm{Rank}\left\{\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{A}\\\mathbf{A'}\mathbf{B}\end{bmatrix}\right\}=m$ is the necessary and sufficient condition iff $\mathbf{A}$ has full row rank.